# Azure Mobile App Service Twitter Authentication iOS 9

Tags: ios, azure, mobile, twitter

We have a Azure mobile app service that uses Twitter authentication. we also have a native swift iOS app that consumes the service. If I run the app on the simulator without the official Twitter app installed then everything is cool and works well, the authorise page is shown, enter details and redirection then takes places as per the Mobile sign in flow.

However when I run this on the device with the Twitter app installed, I enter my details on the authorise page, I tap sign in, the Twitter app is then launched, this then opens up Safari and and I get the something went technically wrong page.

I've tried several different things, I've disabled App Transport Security thinking it might be that, I implemented client-redirection authentication only to find that Twitter is not supported.

I've searched for a couple of days now and can't find anyone else having the issue. Is it me? or has something gone a bit wonky?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: are you getting any error description? As I found Twitter integration is very easy.

Comment: Hi, no I'm not receiving any error description. You're right the integration is easy and this was all working without any problems and still does on the simulator. The problems have only started happening on the physical device running iOS 9.1.

Comment: I would like to ask you to please go on your application page on twitter. Check for all the settings that you have made. Check for all permissions also.

Comment: Thanks Gagan_iOS just to be sure I created a whole new app in Twitter and updated the details in Azure and unfortunately the same thing happens.

Comment: ok..if possible give me your mail id..i will send you working demo.  Moreover what operations(Auth, sharing, update fetching etc) do you want to implement with Twitter. If you just want to Authenticate & share, I would suggest you to please user SocialFramework avaliable from iOS6. More Info https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/index.html 
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone out there I have just received this info from a nice chap at Microsoft: -

*The core issue is that by default Katana (used for login) redirects to twitter.com for oauth and not api.twitter.com, which causes the Native Twitter app (in iOS 9) to intercept it and think its a request to open content in Twitter.
MobileApps will get a fix for this in the next week or so, as it rolls out new auth changes.*